# Excel Finding matching values in a column and comparing the values in another column to one another

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

***EDIT I have to accomplish this in Excel 2016 so I don't have access to Unique or Filter Functions***

I have a table that contains a list of names and addresses and other information.
I want to identify instances where the street address is used more than once, and then compare all the instances of the street address to return a “Match” or “Alert” if the last names of the people at the address do or don’t match.

I created a CountIf Column to identify entries that need to be compared, and a column to pull just the last name.
=COUNTIF([Street],[@[Street]])

=LEFT([@Name],(FIND(" ",[@Name],1)-1))

How can I compare the last names of everyone living at the same address?

Is there a way to use the Filter function here, or will I need VBA?

| ID#s | Name | Last Name | Result | Street | Street Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Brown Bob | Brown |  | Address 1 | 2 |
| 2 | Brown Sue | Brown |  | Address 1 | 2 |
| 3 | Green Adam | Green |  | Address 2 | 2 |
| 4 | Chruchill John | Chruchill |  | Address 2 | 2 |
| 5 | Smith Gary | Smith |  | Address 3 | 3 |
| 6 | Smith Lisa | Smith |  | Address 3 | 3 |
| 7 | Parker Peter | Parker |  | Address 4 | 1 |
| 8 | Parker Lewis | Parker |  | Address 4 | 1 |
| 9 | Smith Evan | Smith |  | Address 3 | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Result:  =IF(COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER([Last Name],[Street]=@[Street])))=1,"Match","Alert")
```

[image]

***Edit:** If you only have Excel 2016, try:*

```
=IF(COUNTIFS([Street],[@Street],[Last Name],[@[Last Name]])=COUNTIF([Street],[@Street]),"Match","Alert")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question. Unfortunately this is a work project and we are stuck with Excel 2016.

Comment: @ZacharyBlankenship In your initial question, you mentioned using the Filter function, so I assumed you had that available.  But see my edit for a solution that should work in earlier versions

Answer (score 0):

This formula returns:

- `Ok` if the `[Street]` is unique *(change as required)*
- `Match` if the `[Street]` is not unique and all the `[Last Name]` for that `[Street]` are the same.
- `Alert` if the `[Street]` is not unique and not all the `[Last Name]` for that `[Street]` are the same.

  ```
  = IF( COUNTIF( [Street], [@Street] ) = 1, "Ok",
   IF( COUNTIF( [Street], [@Street] ) 
   = COUNTIFS( [Street], [@Street], [Last Name], [@[Last Name]] ), "Match", "Alert" ) )
  ```

[image]